# Evaluate the indefinite integral: $\int\frac1{x \sqrt{4x^2 - 9}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

For my final answer I got $\tfrac16 \operatorname{arcsec} |x^2|/3$. I let $u=2x$ and $du=2$. to get $2$ on top as $du$. I multiplied the whole thing by $1/2$ and threw a $2$ in the numerator. That's where I think I messed up.

Comment: Substitute $2x = 3\sec \theta$

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{4x^2-9}}=\int\frac{x\ dx}{x^2\sqrt{4x^2-9}}$$

Let $\displaystyle\sqrt{4x^2-9}=u\implies \frac{8x\ dx}{\sqrt{4x^2-9}}=du$ and $\displaystyle4x^2-9=u^2\iff x^2=\frac{u^2+9}4$

$$\implies I=\frac18\int\frac{4du}{u^2+9}=\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with [hyperbolic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function), let $x=\dfrac32\cosh t$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
With $\ds{x = {3 \over 2}\,\sec\pars{\theta}\quad\imp\quad
          \theta= \arccos\pars{3 \over 2x} = {\rm arcsec}\pars{2x \over 3}}$:

> \begin{align}
> \int{1 \over x\root{4x^{2} - 9}}\,\dd x&
> =\int{1 \over \bracks{\pars{3/2}\sec\pars{\theta}}\bracks{3\tan\pars{\theta}}}\,
> {3 \over 2}\,\sec\pars{\theta}\tan\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta
> ={1 \over 3}\int\dd\theta\\[3mm]&= {1 \over 3}\,\theta + \mbox{a constant}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\int{1 \over x\root{4x^{2} - 9}}\,\dd x
={1 \over 3}\,{\rm arcsec}\pars{2x \over 3}} + \mbox{a constant}
$$